# Cannot Catch error when querying an invalid External Table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, external-tables

When you have an external table created based on a non-existing table from another Azure SQL database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM invalid_external_table
```

The following error message is thrown:

> Msg 46823, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   Error retrieving data from {azure database}. The underlying error message received was: 'Invalid object name 'dbo.invalid_table'.'.

The problem that I'm dealing with is that you seem to be unable to catch this error.

The following code results in the same error:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT * 
    FROM invalid_external_table 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'caught exception'
END CATCH
```

I'm querying an external table in a Azure SQL database that is based on a table from another SQL database.

Is is possible to either catch this error or validate the external table before querying the external table?

Comment: Why do you have an "...external table created based on a non-existing table from another Azure SQL database"?

Comment: That's indeed another issue which should not happen. The external table is generated based on some metadata. I was in general interested in this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql):

> TRY…CATCH constructs do not trap the following conditions:
>
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as
>     object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of
>     deferred name resolution.
>
> If an error occurs during compilation or statement-level recompilation at a lower execution level (for example, when executing sp_executesql or a user-defined stored procedure) inside the TRY block, the error occurs at a lower level than the TRY…CATCH construct and will be handled by the associated CATCH block.

This is not specific to external tables either, the following will throw an error:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.InvalidTable;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'caught exception';
END CATCH
```

But if you execute the SQL dynamically, then you will reach the catch block, e.g:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL N'SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.InvalidTable;';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'caught exception';
END CATCH
```